# presion number and radical output in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

The results are in a bad shape in the following program. On the other hand, I want the results be floats with three digits precision (not symbolic). Is there a trick for all the outputs to be printed in float with three digits precision?

```
from sympy import *

H= Matrix([[ 1.         , 0.05433693 , 0.10472542],
       [ 0.05433693 , 1.       ,   0.85837621],
       [ 0.10472542 , 0.85837621  ,1.        ]])
ppp=Matrix(H)
z=ppp.eigenvals()
pprint(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for k,v in z.items():
...  print '%s, %s' % (k.n(3, chop=True), v)
...
0.178 + 1.13*I, 1
0.178 - 1.13*I, 1
2.64, 1
```